# Three.js: How would I add a longitude/latitude grid to a world globe?

Tags: javascript, three.js, geography

I'm working on a simulation of the famous Prague Astronomical Clock: https://shetline.com/orloj/

I've already produced a lat/lon grid in a crude way, by 2-d drawing lines onto the image which is used for the surface of the globe, but this method doesn't work very well:

[image: Globe screen shot]

(Yes, the globe is supposed to be upside down, as it is on the original clock.)

The grid lines are very jagged this way, and they fade out near the poles because of the scaling near the poles of the original rectangular map image.

I'm trying to find a tutorial on how to do a simple bit of decoration like this by using Three.js/WebGL constructs, but no luck so far. I can get a bit of a start on what I want with the following code:

```
      this.camera = new PerspectiveCamera(FIELD_OF_VIEW, 1);
      this.scene = new Scene();
      const globe = new SphereGeometry(GLOBE_RADIUS, 50, 50);
      globe.rotateY(-PI / 2);
      this.globeMesh = new Mesh(globe, new MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new CanvasTexture(Globe.mapCanvas) }));
      this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
      this.renderer.setSize(GLOBE_PIXEL_SIZE, GLOBE_PIXEL_SIZE);
      this.rendererHost.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
      this.scene.add(this.globeMesh);

      const circle = new Line(new CircleGeometry(GLOBE_RADIUS + 0.1, 50),
        new LineBasicMaterial({ color: GRID_COLOR, linewidth: 20 }));
      this.globeMesh.add(circle);
```

...by adding a circle, and making the edges of the circle poke out just a bit beyond the surface of the globe, but the result is only a very faint line that doesn't respond to my attempts to make the line thicker. I've also tried something similar with a torus floating just above the surface of the globe, but that doesn't work very well either.

[image: Circle as longitude line]

What I want is some sort of additional layer for the lines, or a composite material that combines my pixel image with geometrically-defined lines (rather than painted lines), but I'm not finding the Three.js documentation very clear for figuring out how to do this.

I'm not even sure what kind of geometric model to use for these lines. They're all circles of a sort, but to have a real visual extent it seems the geometry would need to be some sort of globe-hugging, narrow, thin ribbons resting on the surface of the globe.

Comment: I've got 3 options: 1. a texture of a square with border, 2. A grid, drawn with shaders, 3. A sphere geometry with changed index.

Comment: Thanks, @prisoner849. How would I combine a square texture, or any of these other options you suggest, with the pixel image texture?

Comment: The third one: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/sphere-geometry-just-wireframe-but-without-diagonal-lines/4027/8

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using (very, very short) cylinders as my lines of longitude and latitude, floating ever so slightly above the surface of the globe. It seems like anything composed of true line objects can't be guaranteed to honor `linewidth`, and I didn't want to settle for always-one-pixel lines.

The lines of longitude are simple hollow cylinders, as is the equator. All of the other lines of latitude are flared cylinders, wider at one end to conform to the shape of the globe.

[image]

```
const LINE_THICKNESS = 0.03;
const HAG = 0.01; // Sleight distance above globe that longitude/latitude lines are drawn.

// ...

      // Lines of longitude
      for (let n = 0; n < 24; ++n) {
        const line = new CylinderGeometry(GLOBE_RADIUS + HAG, GLOBE_RADIUS + HAG, LINE_THICKNESS, 50, 1, true);
        line.translate(0, -LINE_THICKNESS / 2, 0);
        line.rotateX(PI / 2);
        line.rotateY(n * PI / 12);
        const mesh = new Mesh(line, new MeshBasicMaterial({ color: GRID_COLOR }));
        this.globeMesh.add(mesh);
      }

      // Lines of latitude
      for (let n = 1; n < 12; ++n) {
        const lat = (n - 6) * PI / 12;
        const r = GLOBE_RADIUS * cos(lat);
        const y = GLOBE_RADIUS * sin(lat);
        const r1 = r - LINE_THICKNESS * sin(lat) / 2;
        const r2 = r + LINE_THICKNESS * sin(lat) / 2;
        const line = new CylinderGeometry(r1 + HAG, r2 + HAG, cos(lat) * LINE_THICKNESS, 50, 8, true);
        line.translate(0, -cos(lat) * LINE_THICKNESS / 2 + y, 0);
        const mesh = new Mesh(line, new MeshBasicMaterial({ color: GRID_COLOR }));
        this.globeMesh.add(mesh);
      }
```

Perhaps there is a better way where the lines are part of some sort of texture applied to the globe, but this is at least giving satisfactory results for now.

Comment: This is a good solution. However, rendering 36 separate meshes with the same material is a waste of calculations because each mesh render takes a fraction of a second, but they add up. I recommend you merge all your `CylinderGeometry`s into one (so they can all be rendered at once) with [BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries()](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries) Then you can render the lines in a single mesh in about 1/36th of the time!

Comment: Use `import * as BufferGeometryUtils from "[TheBufferGeometryUtilsURL]"; ... var geo = []; for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {var g = new THREE.SphereGeometry(GLOBE_RADIUS + HAG, 240, 120, 0, Math.PI * 2, THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(i * 15 - LINE_THICKNESS / 2), THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(LINE_THICKNESS)); geo.push(g); if (i === 6) {g.rotateZ(Math.PI / 2); for (var j = 1; j < 12; j++) {g = g.clone().rotateY(THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(15)); geo.push(g);};};}; lines = new THREE.Mesh(BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries(geo), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: GRID_COLOR}));` to follow globe's shape.

Comment: @Marquizzo Yes, rendering the merged thing will happen much faster, but building the separate geometries that will eventually be merged will be proportionally slower. So, there's a trade off here when it comes to speed. Of course, merging geometries will still come on top assuming that building the object will only happen once (or at least, significantly fewer times than rendering it), while we need to render it once every couple of milliseconds in the supposed animation.

Comment: I didn't come back to this question and update my code here, but I did take @Marquizzo's advice. The now-deployed code is here: https://github.com/kshetline/prague-clock/blob/master/src/globe/globe.ts, staring at line 290.

Comment: @kshetline Great to see you made it work - thanks for sharing! I did the same for my globe when it came to geometries of this method, although I prefer using the grid-like image texture variant that can follow altitudes (hills, mountains) via `.displacementMap` on the globe, same with the borders. I'll use this opportunity to apologize for not writing `if (i === 6) {g = g.clone().rotateZ(Math.PI / 2); geo.push(g);` instead, in the code above, to avoid skipping a parallel line. My comment  was also about using sphere "slices" instead of cylinders to better approximate the globe's shape, btw.